# obtener el valor del ultimo dia del mes

Tags: excel

tengo una tabla muy larga de fechas y valores en excel

```
A         B
-------   -------
1/1/17    10
3/1/17    7
31/1/17   6
6/2/17    6
15/2/17   6
23/2/17   98
3/3/17    25
13/3/17   5
31/3/17   18
```

necesito hallar los valores de la columna B para los ultimos valores del mes. de acuerdo al ejemplo para enero seria 6, para febrero 98 y para marzo 18. Deseo hacerlo por medio de formulas y no con VBA.

gracias de antemano...

Comment: puedes agregar lo que hicistes

Answer (score 0):

Esto es lo que se me ocurre sin tener mas información de que requieres:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Hazme saber si funciona o si te puedo ayudar/modificar mi respuesta